# Why is discord.py not recognizing variables outside "on_message()"?

Tags: python, discord, undefined, discord.py

My discord.py script gives me an unexpected error. It basically marks all the variables that I defined outside of `async def on_message():` but used under that as "not defined".

Well, you could easily fix it by defining them under `on_message()` too. Which I tried.
But then, here's the problem: The variables would be set back to what you defined each time a message is sent, even if you did add, like a line saying change it to another value if this hapens. (e.g prefix, as you can see below in the code, I want to change the bot's prefix using a command called "changeprefix" and it works, HOWEVER when another message is sent with that prefix, it wouldn't recognize it; because the line defining the variable at the beginning ran again and it all got reset.

Is there a way else than just removing `on_message()` and using `discord.ext.commands` or something? I'm more familiar with the `on-message()` system, moreover I would change the whole script if I switch to it.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
token= "some nice token"
#defining here results in "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prefix' referenced before assignment", in the first line using the variable defined here

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
     #defining here results variables being refreshed each time a message is sent
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `global` here is a simple example on how to use it.

```py
something = 1

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global something
    something = something + 1
    print(something) # 2 at first iteration

#outside of on_message
print(something) # 2 it is the same
```

In case you want to use it with prefix make it a dict with `guild.id` as key and the value is the prefix.

btw using commands would be much easier to do so.

**NOTE:** If you restart your bot you are going to lose this info

Comment: I want the variable to not be renewed constantly, as it does in on_message. What you show is, I guess, defining it inside the function but also making it global so that it's going to be counted as a variable even when you mention it outside.

Comment: You were right. I found this question randomly after months, and re-read your answer. I, back then thought this was for defining global variables in somewhere where any declaration would be local. But from what I understand, it's for referring to a global variable that is already created. My thought was already not so logical, while you can already create global variables outside of somewhere like that. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: And, what do you recommend to prevent the situation you noted at the end? I think it happens with any script that is re-initializing everything everytime the code is run. Perhaps I can use another file for storing info for the current device, and a database/server for multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

*If I understood your question correctly* you want a variable that will change it's value everytime a command is invoked, you can use a global variable (I don't recommend it) or a bot var. Also use `commands.Bot` so you can use the command system

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
```

```py
# Using a global variable
my_var = 'my value'

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    global my_var
    my_var = arg
    await ctx.send(f"Changed `my_var` value to `arg`")
```

```py
# Using a bot var
bot.my_var = 'my value'

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    bot.my_var = arg
    await ctx.send(f"Changed `bot.my_var` value to `arg`")
```

Comment: I want the variable to not be renewed constantly, as it does in on_message. What you show is, I guess, defining it inside the function but also making it global so that it's going to be counted as a variable even when you mention it outside.

Comment: You were right. I found this question randomly after months, and re-read your answer. I, back then thought global keyword was for defining global variables in somewhere where any declaration would be local. But from what I understand, it's for referring to a global variable that is already created. My thought was already not so logical, while you can already create global variables outside of somewhere like that. For the bot command part, I hadn't even seen it when I first found your answer. Sorry for misleading.